# How to store loose CDs and other discs without scratching them?

Tags: substitute-tool, technology, storage

At home I have a load of loose disks that I have either lost the case for or it never had a case in the first place and these usually end up getting scratched up and quickly become unusable, not to mention they are even easier to lose as they can slip down small cracks never to be seen again!

> **Does anyone know of how I can store loose discs without scratching them?**

I would prefer not to have to go out a buy one of those disk wallets that can store many disks - granted this would be a good solution but I wanted to see if there were any alternatives before spending money on anything!

Comment: You want the CDs as it is ? I mean you don't want to copy it into another source like for eg. a HDD?

Comment: @EroSennin I would rather keep hold of the CDs but if nothing else, transferring them to a digital medium would be an option!

Comment: It's not 1999 anymore. Copy the cds to your computer/phone and then store them on a spindle in the closet. After 10 years find them again and toss them out because they do nothing but take up space.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I always use standard A4 printing paper. Very cheap and available almost anywhere.

Put each disk on a piece of paper, right at the centre. Then fold the long edges, next fold the short edges, like shown in the picture. (Make it a reasonably tight fit, so the disk won't slide around inside this envelope, because paper is slightly abrassive, theoretically.)

That's all. No tape required, the disk won't slip out of the envelope easily.

[image: A4 paper CD cover]

Comment: I like this method - doesn't require buying anything new and they can be easily labelled and stored away!

Comment: This does indeed work, and if you fold the long edges slightly non-parallel to the sides you are able to push the narrow end into the wider end and lock the envelope.

Answer (score 9):

I use a CD "spindle" - you get them when you buy bulk blank CDs and DVDs.
It tidies them up and keeps them relatively scratch free.   However, whilst it keeps them tidy it just transfers the problem down the line when you want to retrieve the CD from the stack... you have to be quite careful not to scratch them... probably best for archive CDs that you won't use very often.

Answer (score 2):

I've been in the same situation and I've done three things :

**1. Single CD cases**

**2.Plastic packet-type case**

**3. External Hard Disk**

I use the single CD cases to store the games . Although it is not a suitable method for storing every single CD you've got , it can be used to store the important ones (ie. Console games,Premium software etc).

I'm not sure what they are generally called as, but they're for single CDs or two(front&back) , cheap, prevents scratches and durable. I'll leave a description of it, since I don't know what it is called:

> Plastic packet with some kind of plastic fiber inside it to prevent CDs from getting scratched. It has two storage areas on either side.

If you've a bunch of CD (less important but still useful) , the HDD is feasible, but of course, its time consuming to copy the files from the CD to the HDD.

**IMO** the disk wallet is highly efficient compared to my amateurish suggestions :P

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plastic freezer bag with a bubble envelope. Ultimate solution I suggest is a plastic CD case.